# Storing Nested Objects

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an object of Type Parent, which has children of type Parent and so on .
which data-type is best for storing this kind of data..
Addition of the objects is dynamic ,as the user adds the obects it in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Since the name `Parent` is semantically misleading I'll substitute it for `Node`, to paraphrase your question as code,

```
class Node : IEnumerable<Node> { }
```

Now, you say you want to support dynamic change. If there will be a little change, or generally wholesale changes I'd go with

```
class Node : List<Node> { }
```

but if there will be a lot of small changes,

```
class Node : LinkedList<Node> { }
```

may prove more suitable.

---

If you want to support many small changes to your tree, I wouldn't use xml as a backing store. Whilst this seems to make sense, and works fine for sensibly sized trees, when the tree is large and you add or remove data near the start of the document you get a noticable [Shlemiel The Painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) effect as memory is (de)allocated and the tail is shifted. Unless you happen to be using an XML Document implementation that avoids this.

The advantage of using XML is the free serialization but XML is not the most consice way to store your private data. Faster and smaller alternatives exist.